# Can I have a Photoshop action pause itself to wait for user input?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

I am new to photoshop. I want the action to pause , then I want a user to be able to select his own path via a selection tool, and then the rest of the action should run. How is this achievable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by ticking the little button to the left of the item you'd like Photoshop to pause on.

[image]

---- EDIT -----

Another option to allow user interaction is inserting a stop action.

1. Select the item in the action that you would like to stop after.
2. Click the flyout menu in the Actions panel, and choose Insert Stop...

[image]

3. Type a message, so the user knows what they're supposed to do.

[image]

### Using the action

now when playing through the action it will stop where you told it to and you can do what ever you need, then you have to click the paly button again.

Comment: But it is not ticking

Comment: Not all steps in an action can be set to require user input, can you expand your question a little so we know exactly what you're needing?

Comment: Well i did write it but it got edited. I want a user to be able to edit the path taken via a quick selection tool after it has been selected.

Comment: I want the action to stop for the path selection only. Now while making the action after selecting quick selection what do i do?

Comment: I updated the answer...

Comment: @Hamza No problem!

Comment: I would've voted up but it requires 15 reputation. Would do it once i reach that mark :)

Comment: This in incorrect, "now when playing through the action it will stop where you told it to and you can do what ever you need, then you have to click the paly button again."   You can not "Do whatever you want", in fact you can not interact with anything because it is a modal dialogue.